# Stemming and Lemmatisation using Stanford NLP library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford NLP library for Stemming and Lemmatisation. I followed the example on their documentation

```
def plainTextToLemmas(text: String, stopWords: Set[String]): List[String] = {
      val props = new Properties()
      props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")
      val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
      //empty annotation with given text
      val doc = new Annotation(text)
      //run annotators on text
      pipeline.annotate(doc)
      val lemmas = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
      val sentences = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
      for (sentence <- sentences; token <- sentence.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation])) {
        val lemma = token.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation])
        if (lemma.length > 2 && !stopWords.contains(lemma)) {
          lemmas += lemma.toLowerCase
        }
      }
      lemmas.toList
    }

val x = sentence.map(plainTextToLemmas(_, stopWords))
```

However, it does not lemmatize sentences without space after the fullstop very well. Is there an option to fix this? Also can there be an option to filter html tags? Adding it to the stopwords is not working.

Comment: you should clean your text by parsing HTML tags before sending it to the method (after all, it is called "plainText..."), adding tags to stopwords is not the right approach

Comment: Thank you. Will take that advice.  Do you have suggestion on treating sentences where there is no space after a full stop? The library does not lemmatize such sentences very well either.

Comment: Yes many libraries will expect a whitespace after the period at the end of sentences, in order to better parse tokens that can contain periods (like URLs, company names and acronyms). I can't tell specifically for the Stanford library if there are settings to manage that. If you don't find any then an option is to insert whitespace yourself with a regex after a period, but you are likely to split more than what you asked for.